# Hardly to find out why we use Request::is() and @can in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project in which I found a code with Request::is in blade.php file, I searched but unable to find out exactly why we use it.

There is also a keyword can, what is use of this keyword?
See the code below:

```
@can('index' , App\Category::class)
    <li class=" @if (Request::is('category') || Request::is('addcategory')) {{'active'}} @endif">
@endcan
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-blade-templates & https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests

Comment: It just highlights the link if it's the same as the URL. You can also use Javascript or Jquery to achieve this.

Comment: What about App\Category::class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line of code  the Request::is is used to check if the current url on your browser is equal to the given url . If so then put it to active class .

For e.g if your url is /category on the web url and category on your li is same then put active class on that one

Comment: Got it. Your answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to check if your current path matches the pattern provided in the method `is()`.

In this case, it's used to highlight the menu you are in.

Comment: anything more about Request::is(). Is it just for routing?

Comment: @RohitKumarSharma is is just to determining If the request path matches a pattern (you can use `*` in it)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, the [is()](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L182) method determine if the current request URI matches with pattern.

So the code below should be fine to understand.

```
@if(Request::is('login', 'categories', 'posts', 'posts/{$post->id}'))
```